# x86 Updating GDT in Long Mode

Tags: x86, operating-system, x86-64, gdt

Once in long mode, is there a straightforward way of loading a new GDT without immediately causing a general protection fault?

The issue is that as soon as the new GDT is loaded with `lgdt`, it seems that fetching the next instruction will immediately fault as the `CS` register has not been updated to point to the correct entry in the new table.

The only way I can see of updating a GDT is to copy over the original descriptors into the new table, and then add any new entries to the end. This way, the new GDT is "backwards compatible" with the old one, and so the active segment selectors will still be valid.

This seems like a convoluted solution - is there an easier way?

Comment: There shouldn't be a fault unless an actual segment register is reloaded with a new value that is invalid. Usually though the next instruction after replacing the LGDT should be a far jmp to reload the CS register and then you reload all the other segment registers (ds,es,fs,gs, ss). I'm curious though when you did the LGDT were interrupts on? Because if you got an interrupt at the very least the CS segment would be reloaded when it hits the IRETQ. If the CS in the interrupt descriptor is wrong that would cause a problem.

Comment: "There shouldn't be a fault unless an actual segment register is reloaded with a new value that is invalid" - does this mean that the CPU "caches" the segment descriptors somewhere, rather than looking up the descriptor from the index on every memory access? (That would make sense from a performance perspective but I hadn't seen it written down anywhere).

Comment: Also to answer your question, interrupts are off when I'm calling `lgdt`. Perhaps there's another reason why I'm getting a protection fault; to be honest I didn't debug too rigorously as I didn't understand on a conceptual level why it wouldn't always fault when fetching the next instruction.

Comment: It is explicit in the description of the MOV instruction as well as in the "Protected Mode Memory Management" chapter of volume 3 of the Intel SDM. "In protected mode, moving a segment selector into a segment register automatically causes the segment descriptor information associated with that segment selector to be loaded into the hidden (shadow) part of the segment register."

Comment: Yes, the CPU uses cached versions of segment register information until the segment registers are actually reloaded. And as you noted that saves the CPU from making a trip to the descriptor table on every memory access. In the Intel Architecture Software Development Manuals (SDM) in [volume 3](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/671447) section 3.4.3 "Segment Registers" there is a description of the descriptor caches.

Comment: Ah whoops, looks like I missed that detail when reading through the manual. Thanks both.

Comment: If you run your OS/program in QEMU with the `-d int -no-shutdown -no-reboot` it should tell you all the interrupts and exceptions that occur. You probably can determine what the cause of the exception is and where it happens by looking at that output. I have a feeling that the next instruction after the LGDT isn't the cause of the issue.

Comment: The "descriptor caches" aren't really caches in the way that TLB and L1i/L1d / etc. are.  They're internal state that you set by reloading a segment register in a mode other than real mode.  (Or for FS and GS base, via an MSR or `wrfsbase` / `wrgsbase` in 64-bit mode.)  Besides not being coherent with changes to anything else, "descriptor caches" are guaranteed to keep their values if you don't do anything, never randomly evicted, so for example a hypervisor context-switch needs to save/restore them separately.